# How to Insert rows into a single column in an empty dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following empty dataframe/tibble:

```
new_table <- tibble(
  country = character(),
  code = character()

)
```

Which is empty after creating it 0 rows x 2 columns

And i have the following data frame of codes:

```
df_codes <- tibble(codes = c('CH','US','UK'))
```

which looks like this:

```
codes 
-----
CH
US
UK
```

Is there  way of looping through each element in the df_codes dataframe and inserting these values into my new_table dataframes code column?

I have tried the following code but to no avail:

```
for(c in unique(df_codes$codes)){

new_table <- new_table %>% mutate(code = c)

return(new_table)
}
```

But this returns still a dataframe with 0 rows and 2 columns:

Ideally i would like this output when calling new_table:

```
country|code
-------|-----
NA     | CH
NA     | US
NA     | UK
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You are returning (where from?) right after the first time through the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(new_table, df_codes)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  country code 
#  <chr>   <chr>
#1 <NA>    CH   
#2 <NA>    US   
#3 <NA>    UK
```

---

Or instead of using `bind_rows`, this can be done with `base R` by doing an assignment

```
new_table[seq_len(nrow(df_codes)), names(df_codes)] <- df_codes
```

where

```
df_codes <- tibble(code = c('CH','US','UK'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option is `merge`

```
merge(new_table,df_codes, by.x = "code", by.y = "codes",all = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
  code country
1   CH    <NA>
2   UK    <NA>
3   US    <NA>
```